# Where could I find the ssl.conf file in a CentOS server?

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, centos, ssl-certificate

My `/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` contains this line:

`SSLProtocol TLSv1.2`

Nonetheless, I was told that I needed to identify what is defined for SSLProtocol in `ssl.conf`. Where can I find this file? I have a CentOS server.

UPDATE 1: Nevermind, I do not require an answer anymore, it was all a confusion with the scan report referring to a wrong IP address, not the one that I needed to evaluate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ssl.conf on CentOS is usually located /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

If this file is not present, then you probably did not install Apache mod_ssl.

To install mod_ssl:

```
sudo yum install mod_ssl
```

Comment: I do have `/etc/apache2/conf.d` but not the `ssl.conf` within that folder. I only see these two folders: `/etc/apache2/conf.d/ssl.key/` and `/etc/apache2/conf.d/ssl.crt/`. Apparently I do not have installed this Apache mod_ssl that you mention. Do I even need it? What I am really trying to do is to disable TLS v.1.0. I was trying to do it from `/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` but using this line: `SSLProtocol TLSv1.2`. But I guess I would need something like this to disable it?: `SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2`. Thanks.